# Spring Boot Scanning Classes from jars issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my sample spring boot application, i have added a dependency of a custom jar. My sample application has a support for web and jpa.

The jar which i've created contains a Spring MVC controller. Below is the sample code

```
@Controller
public class StartStopDefaultMessageListenerContainerController {
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private Map<String, DefaultMessageListenerContainer> messageListeners;
```

I haven't manually created a bean instance of this controller anywhere in my code.

Problem - When i start my spring boot application by running the main class, i get an error in console that prob while autowiring DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

My question here is, even though this class StartStopDefaultMessageListenerContainerController is just present in the classpath, it's bean shouldn't be created and autowiring should not happen. But spring boot is scanning the class automatically and then it tries to autowire the fields.

Is this the normal behavior of spring and is there anyway i can avoid this?

Comment: And why shouldn't it be created? If it falls under a package that is scanned it will be created, so at first I would say yes this is what should happen.

Comment: so i am not putting it under any package scanner.I have just added the jar in my pom.xml. As far as i know, Spring boot automatically scans all the classes which fall under same package where @SpringBootApplication annotated class is present.

Comment: And all sub packages. Also if another `@Configuration` is present with additional `@ComponentScan` then it is also effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `StartStopDefaultMessageListenerContainerController` class is part of `component scanning` by spring container, Yes spring tries to instantiate and resolve all dependencies.

Here your problem is **@Autowired** on collection. Spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) says,

> Beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.

And also Refer [inject-empty-map-via-spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407569/inject-empty-map-via-spring#comment56564051_34407569)

Comment: StartStopDefaultMessageListenerContainerController is present in xyz.jar which is just added in my pom.xml. i am not not explicitely scanning the class neither creating its bean

Comment: read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Comment: i understand this, difference here is, it scans all the classes from application. Question here is, why does it scans the classes from jars as well?